# Firebase database reference error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On running the code below, I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

I am getting the error on the line `dataRef.child(dbs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()`. I am not sure what is the problem.

```
public class UTFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedCollname= prefs.getString("collname", null);
        dataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(savedCollname);
}

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
UTFragment utFragment = new UTFragment();
            UTFragment.MyAsync myTask = utFragment.new MyAsync(dbs,data);
            myTask.execute();
}

class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
String dbs;
 public MyAsync(String dbs){
this.dbs = dbs;
}
@Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
dataRef.child(dbs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //do something
}}
```

Comment: The error means that `dataRef` hasn't been initialized yet when you call `child(...)` on it. So most likely your fragment's `onCreateView` hasn't been called when the task updates its progress.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but this a weird scenario. May I ask: Why are you creating a second Fragment inside that same Fragment? And why are you using an AsyncTask to load Firebase data?

Comment: To show progress bar I have used async task. There are lot more things going on I have just shown the relevant code. @RosárioPereiraFernandes

Comment: Understood... As Frank mentioned, the AsyncTask is calling `child()` in `dataRef` before it has been initialized. So I recommend initializing the DatabaseReference in your AsyncTask.

Comment: When I initialise DatabaseReference in AsyncTask it gives me the error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method `'android.content.SharedPreferences android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference` @RosárioPereiraFernandes

Comment: I kinda saw that coming. That's why I asked you why creating the second Fragment... What's happening is that when you instantiate the new `UTFragment` it is not attached to any activity, so your `getActivity()` returns `null` thus you can't get a reference to the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Since I am passing arguments to the AsyncTask I had to create second fragment. IS there any other way? @RosárioPereiraFernandes

Comment: Yes, I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you instantiate the fragment for the second time. You don't need a second fragment to be able to use the AsyncTask. You can simply call for the AsyncTask:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            MyAsync myTask = new MyAsync(dbs,data);
            myTask.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says very clearly what the problem is. Your field `dataRef` isn't initialized yet by the time you are calling `child()` method on it, with other words has the value of `null`.

To solve this, `onCreateView()` method must be called before your task updates its progress.